# Generate calendar invite through Firebase Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, calendar, google-cloud-functions

Im using **Firebase** and are looking for a way to **generate a iCal/vcs file** on a certain trigger. I've been looking into [**ics.js**](https://github.com/nwcell/ics.js)  but i'm not sure if this is the way to go.

**Background**

So the user creates an event using a app, this gets sent to Firebase, and this should trigger a event (the trigger already exists) where the calendar invite is being sent with **nodemailer**

*Is this even possible?*

Comment: Hi Giovanni, did you get anywhere with this? I'm considering doing something similar for an app I'm working on.

Comment: Hi, no progress so far unfortunately. I will probably just use the devices own standard calendar, so for instance on iOS call EventKit or on Android call Google calendar...

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Create a mail transport

```
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
service: 'gmail',
auth: {
    user: gmailEmail,
    pass: gmailPassword,
 },
});
```

Create cal event

```
// Create ical object
let cal = ical();

const event = cal.createEvent({
    start: event_start,
    summary: event_name,
    end: new Date(event_start.getTime() + 3600000),
    location: address
});

event.organizer({
    name: author_name,
    email: author_email,
    mailto: author_email
});

// Update event description
event.description(email_text);

// Set up mail options
const mailOptions = {
                    from: `"Your corp." <${gmailEmail}`,
                    to: user_email,
                    subject: `Here is your event"`,
                    text: email_text,
                    icalEvent: {
                        method: 'request',
                        content: new Buffer(cal.toString())
                    }
                    };



// Send mailOptions
mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions).then(() => console.log(`Invite sent`
                                   .catch((error) => console.error('There was an error while sending the email:', error));
```